# How to include multiple IF statements in one cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to change the value of a cell in Google Sheets based on the value of an adjacent cell. This adjacent cell gets its value from the colour of the cell adjacent to it using the formula from [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-filter-by-color-in-Google-Sheets) Quora answer. So the value of the cell should change based on the hex code which is obtained from the colour of the first cell. There are four possible hex values at the moment so I was trying to put four different IF statements in the same cell, so its value is changed based on this.

My first attempt led to a formula parse error:

```
=if((J2="#00ff00","Read"), if(j2="#ff0000", "Unread"), if(j2="#ff9900","In Progress"), if(j2="#000000", "Not Applicable"))
```

It is clear you cannot simply separate if statements with commas. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587898/google-spreadsheet-multiple-if-statements-between-number-ranges) Stack Overflow question I tried this code, with nested IF statements:

```
=if((J2="#00ff00","Read", if(j2="#ff0000", "Unread", if(j2="#ff9900","In Progress",if(j2="#000000", "Not Applicable")))))
```

This also leads to a formula parse error.

Is there any way I can simply include multiple IF statements in the same cell which will work for my code?

Comment: Can you combine them into an =OR or something similar?

Comment: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Comment: I think the `IFS` function is a more elegant solution than any of the answers: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en -- just adding it as I found this from a search and none of the answers were really clever enough.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`lookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570/?hl=en&authuser=0) instead of `if`:

```
=lookup(B7,
       {"#000000","#00ff00","#ff0000","#ff9900"},
       {"Not applicable", "Read","Unread","In Progress"}
  )
```

Note the second parameter must be a sorted list.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the items in the 3rd argument are expression

Comment: Note that the first array (the "key" array) has to be sorted (it worked when mine was alphabetically sorted ascendingly) for it to work as intended.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek, is there a way around this, or do you just have to use nested `ifs`?

Answer (score 23):

## Short answer

The problem in the examples provided are the parenthesis. Apply them properly.

## Explanation

`IF()` function should have two parameters and optionally a third one.

```
IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

The specific problem with

- the first example provided is that the outer `IF()` has too many parameters.
- the second example is that the `logical_expression` of the outer `IF()` do not return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

In Google Sheets the functions parameters are separated by commas (or semicolons if your spreadsheet uses comma as decimal separator).
When parenthesis are used to enclose several operations and functions inside a function they are considered as a parameter of the function that contains them.

A common practice is to put the inner `IF()` as the `value_if_false`, but it could be done in many ways. Adding `IF()` inside another other as `value_if_true` and `value_if_false` is called `IF() logical test nesting` or just `IF() nesting`.

Below is an example of a formula that have having three `IF()`, two of them used to determine the `value_if_false` of the parent `IF()`. A multi-line and vertical align of parenthesis style is applied for readability

```
 =IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, 
     IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, 
        IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false
          )
       )
    )
```

The above style could be used in Google Sheets formula writing. I found it useful for formula debugging.

## Reference

- [IF - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: Very useful, especially the formatted multiline sample - made it much easier to understand and implement.

Comment: Thank you... this helped me fix my problem.

Comment: You can also look at the `IFS` function: 
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

I just found out how to combine if and or.

Example:

```
=IF(OR(B3>49,C3>49,D3>49),”Passed”,”Failed”)
=IF(AND(B3>49,C3>49,D3>49),”Passed”,”Failed”)
=IF(OR(AND(B3>49,C3>49),AND(B3>49,D3>49),AND(C3>49,D3>49)),”Won”,”Failed”)
```

So for your example:

```
= if(OR(J2="#00ff00",j2="#ff0000",j2="#ff9900"),"True","False")
```

Source: [Combined Use of IF, AND, OR Logical Functions in Google Doc Spreadsheet](http://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/combined-use-of-if-and-or-logical-functions-in-google-doc-spreadsheet/).

Answer (score 2):

You can nest IF statements for example

```
If(if(if(when all 3 equal true)))
```

Would work

OR

you could use a nested IFAND
for example

```
IF(AND(AND()))
```

Would also work.

Comment: The IF() function requires at least two parameters. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89068/88163

Answer (score 1):

You have been offered theory and better approaches but to answer specifically:

> Is there any way I can simply include multiple IF statements in the same cell which will work for my code?

please try:

```
=if(J2="#00ff00","Read", if(J2="#ff0000", "Unread", if(J2="#ff9900","In Progress",if(J2="#000000", "Not Applicable"))))
```

That is, your second attempt without the first opening parenthesis and without the last closing parenthesis.